# Same SQL Query is taking more time in production box but less time in machine with lesser capacity

Tags: sql

I have a peculiar issue with one of my sql query which I can not finetune/modify as it is hardcoded with my tailor made application. I think the issue is not with the query but with the Server. I have upgraded sql 2008 to sql 2012. The query is taking less time (3 seconds) in low capacity machines but taking 10 seconds to execute in my production box. The issue is lying with the 'Order by' clause. If I takeout 'Order by' then it is taking only 3 seconds. Query is as follows:- (Even without index it is working fine as the source tables have rows lesser than 100,000)

I am executing this query directly in my production box thru Mangement Studio. Please let me know what may be the possible reason or I should go for a fresh installation of SQL Server 2012 ?

```
exec sp_executesql N'SET ROWCOUNT @PageSize_page_size_11
SELECT fk0.ahi_change_status ahi_change_status,
[AHI_EVENT_SKU].ahi_cleared_warehouse_ship_act ahi_cleared_warehouse_ship_act,
[AHI_EVENT_SKU].ahi_collection ahi_collection,
fk1.keyed_name AS ahi_collection_$_keyed_name,
''ahi_collection'' AS ahi_collection_$_type,
(SELECT p 
 FROM   [GetDiscoverPermissions_9309] (@$t_perm_tp_1, fk1.permission_id, fk1.created_by_id, fk1.managed_by_id, fk1.owned_by_id, fk1.team_id, @$t_iden_list_2, @$t_ip_addr_3, @$t_cur_user_id_4, @$Crtr, @$Mngr, @$Ownr)) AS ahi_collection_$_permission,
fk0.ahi_ensemble_number ahi_ensemble_number,
fk2.keyed_name AS ahi_ensemble_number_$_keyed_name,
''ahi_ensemble'' AS ahi_ensemble_number_$_type,
(SELECT p 
 FROM   [GetDiscoverPermissions_9309] (@$t_perm_tp_1, fk2.permission_id, fk2.created_by_id, fk2.managed_by_id, fk2.owned_by_id, fk2.team_id, @$t_iden_list_2, @$t_ip_addr_3, @$t_cur_user_id_4, @$Crtr, @$Mngr, @$Ownr)) AS ahi_ensemble_number_$_permission,
[AHI_EVENT_SKU].ahi_in_warehouse_act ahi_in_warehouse_act,
ISNULL([AHI_EVENT_SKU].ahi_intro, ''0'')  ahi_intro,
fk0.ahi_primary_event ahi_primary_event,
fk3.keyed_name AS ahi_primary_event_$_keyed_name,
''ahi_eventcode'' AS ahi_primary_event_$_type,
(SELECT p 
 FROM   [GetDiscoverPermissions_9309] (@$t_perm_tp_1, fk3.permission_id, fk3.created_by_id, fk3.managed_by_id, fk3.owned_by_id, fk3.team_id, @$t_iden_list_2, @$t_ip_addr_3, @$t_cur_user_id_4, @$Crtr, @$Mngr, @$Ownr)) AS ahi_primary_event_$_permission,
fk4.state ahi_product_line_state,
fk4.ahi_type ahi_product_line_type,
fk4.ahi_season ahi_season,
fk0.ahi_season_code ahi_season_code,
fk5.keyed_name AS ahi_season_code_$_keyed_name,
''ahi_seasoncode'' AS ahi_season_code_$_type,
(SELECT p 
 FROM   [GetDiscoverPermissions_9309] (@$t_perm_tp_1, fk5.permission_id, fk5.created_by_id, fk5.managed_by_id, fk5.owned_by_id, fk5.team_id, @$t_iden_list_2, @$t_ip_addr_3, @$t_cur_user_id_4, @$Crtr, @$Mngr, @$Ownr)) AS ahi_season_code_$_permission,
[AHI_EVENT_SKU].ahi_ship_consol_act ahi_ship_consol_act,
[AHI_EVENT_SKU].ahi_sku_approved_prod_act ahi_sku_approved_prod_act,
[AHI_EVENT_SKU].ahi_sku_art_comp_dt_act ahi_sku_art_comp_dt_act,
[AHI_EVENT_SKU].ahi_sku_art_out_act ahi_sku_art_out_act,
fk0.ahi_description ahi_sku_desciption,
fk0.state ahi_sku_lc_state,
fk0.ahi_license ahi_sku_licensor,
fk6.keyed_name AS ahi_sku_licensor_$_keyed_name,
''ahi_license'' AS ahi_sku_licensor_$_type,
(SELECT p 
 FROM   [GetDiscoverPermissions_9309] (@$t_perm_tp_1, fk6.permission_id, fk6.created_by_id, fk6.managed_by_id, fk6.owned_by_id, fk6.team_id, @$t_iden_list_2, @$t_ip_addr_3, @$t_cur_user_id_4, @$Crtr, @$Mngr, @$Ownr)) AS ahi_sku_licensor_$_permission,
ISNULL(fk0.ahi_is_new, ''0'')  ahi_sku_new,
fk0.ahi_productnumber ahi_sku_number,
fk0.ahi_pm_owner ahi_sku_pm_owner,
fk7.keyed_name AS ahi_sku_pm_owner_$_keyed_name,
''Identity'' AS ahi_sku_pm_owner_$_type,
9 AS ahi_sku_pm_owner_$_permission,
fk0.ahi_statuscode ahi_sku_wholesale_status,
fk8.keyed_name AS ahi_sku_wholesale_status_$_keyed_name,
''ahi_statuscode'' AS ahi_sku_wholesale_status_$_type,
(SELECT p 
 FROM   [GetDiscoverPermissions_9309] (@$t_perm_tp_1, fk8.permission_id, fk8.created_by_id, fk8.managed_by_id, fk8.owned_by_id, fk8.team_id, @$t_iden_list_2, @$t_ip_addr_3, @$t_cur_user_id_4, @$Crtr, @$Mngr, @$Ownr)) AS ahi_sku_wholesale_status_$_permission,
ISNULL(fk4.ahi_special_project, ''0'')  ahi_special_project,
fk0.ahi_style ahi_style,
fk9.keyed_name AS ahi_style_$_keyed_name,
''ahi_style'' AS ahi_style_$_type,
(SELECT p 
 FROM   [GetDiscoverPermissions_9309] (@$t_perm_tp_1, fk9.permission_id, fk9.created_by_id, fk9.managed_by_id, fk9.owned_by_id, fk9.team_id, @$t_iden_list_2, @$t_ip_addr_3, @$t_cur_user_id_4, @$Crtr, @$Mngr, @$Ownr)) AS ahi_style_$_permission,
[AHI_EVENT_SKU].created_by_id created_by_id,
fk10.keyed_name AS created_by_id_$_keyed_name,
''User'' AS created_by_id_$_type,
9 AS created_by_id_$_permission,
[AHI_EVENT_SKU].created_on created_on,
[AHI_EVENT_SKU].css css,
[AHI_EVENT_SKU].current_state current_state,
fk11.keyed_name AS current_state_$_keyed_name,
''Life Cycle State'' AS current_state_$_type,
9 AS current_state_$_permission,
[AHI_EVENT_SKU].id id,
[AHI_EVENT_SKU].keyed_name AS id_$_keyed_name,
''ahi_event_sku'' AS id_$_type,
id_$_permission = CASE
WHEN [AHI_EVENT_SKU].permission_id = @perms_having_can_get_id THEN 9
ELSE 9
END,
[AHI_EVENT_SKU].keyed_name keyed_name,
[AHI_EVENT_SKU].locked_by_id locked_by_id,
fk12.keyed_name AS locked_by_id_$_keyed_name,
''User'' AS locked_by_id_$_type,
9 AS locked_by_id_$_permission,
[AHI_EVENT_SKU].major_rev major_rev,
[AHI_EVENT_SKU].modified_by_id modified_by_id,
fk13.keyed_name AS modified_by_id_$_keyed_name,
''User'' AS modified_by_id_$_type,
9 AS modified_by_id_$_permission,
[AHI_EVENT_SKU].modified_on modified_on,
[AHI_EVENT_SKU].related_id related_id,
fk0.keyed_name AS related_id_$_keyed_name,
''ahi_sku'' AS related_id_$_type,
(SELECT p 
 FROM   [GetDiscoverPermissions_9309] (@$t_perm_tp_1, fk0.permission_id, fk0.created_by_id, fk0.managed_by_id, fk0.owned_by_id, fk0.team_id, @$t_iden_list_2, @$t_ip_addr_3, @$t_cur_user_id_4, @$Crtr, @$Mngr, @$Ownr)) AS related_id_$_permission,
[AHI_EVENT_SKU].source_id source_id,
fk4.keyed_name AS source_id_$_keyed_name,
''ahi_event'' AS source_id_$_type,
(SELECT p 
 FROM   [GetDiscoverPermissions_9309] (@$t_perm_tp_1, fk4.permission_id, fk4.created_by_id, fk4.managed_by_id, fk4.owned_by_id, fk4.team_id, @$t_iden_list_2, @$t_ip_addr_3, @$t_cur_user_id_4, @$Crtr, @$Mngr, @$Ownr)) AS source_id_$_permission,
[AHI_EVENT_SKU].related_id related_id,
fk0.keyed_name AS related_id_$_keyed_name,
''ahi_sku'' AS related_id_$_type,
(SELECT p 
 FROM   [GetDiscoverPermissions_9309] (@$t_perm_tp_1, fk0.permission_id, fk0.created_by_id, fk0.managed_by_id, fk0.owned_by_id, fk0.team_id, @$t_iden_list_2, @$t_ip_addr_3, @$t_cur_user_id_4, @$Crtr, @$Mngr, @$Ownr)) AS related_id_$_permission,
[AHI_EVENT_SKU].source_id source_id,
fk4.keyed_name AS source_id_$_keyed_name,
''ahi_event'' AS source_id_$_type,
(SELECT p 
 FROM   [GetDiscoverPermissions_9309] (@$t_perm_tp_1, fk4.permission_id, fk4.created_by_id, fk4.managed_by_id, fk4.owned_by_id, fk4.team_id, @$t_iden_list_2, @$t_ip_addr_3, @$t_cur_user_id_4, @$Crtr, @$Mngr, @$Ownr)) AS source_id_$_permission
 FROM [AHI_EVENT_SKU]
 LEFT JOIN [AHI_SKU] fk0
 ON ([AHI_EVENT_SKU].related_id = fk0.id)
 LEFT JOIN [AHI_COLLECTION] fk1
 ON ([AHI_EVENT_SKU].ahi_collection = fk1.id)
 LEFT JOIN [AHI_ENSEMBLE] fk2
 ON (fk0.ahi_ensemble_number = fk2.id)
 LEFT JOIN [AHI_EVENTCODE] fk3
 ON (fk0.ahi_primary_event = fk3.id)
 LEFT JOIN [AHI_EVENT] fk4
 ON ([AHI_EVENT_SKU].source_id = fk4.id)
 LEFT JOIN [AHI_SEASONCODE] fk5
 ON (fk0.ahi_season_code = fk5.id)
 LEFT JOIN [AHI_LICENSE] fk6
 ON (fk0.ahi_license = fk6.id)
 LEFT JOIN [IDENTITY] fk7
 ON (fk0.ahi_pm_owner = fk7.id)
 LEFT JOIN [AHI_STATUSCODE] fk8
 ON (fk0.ahi_statuscode = fk8.id)
 LEFT JOIN [AHI_STYLE] fk9
 ON (fk0.ahi_style = fk9.id)
 LEFT JOIN [USER] fk10
 ON ([AHI_EVENT_SKU].created_by_id = fk10.id)
 LEFT JOIN [LIFE_CYCLE_STATE] fk11
 ON ([AHI_EVENT_SKU].current_state = fk11.id)
 LEFT JOIN [USER] fk12
 ON ([AHI_EVENT_SKU].locked_by_id = fk12.id)
 LEFT JOIN [USER] fk13
 ON ([AHI_EVENT_SKU].modified_by_id = fk13.id)
 WHERE ([AHI_EVENT_SKU].permission_id = @perms_having_can_get OR (
    SELECT p FROM [GetDiscoverPermissions_9309] 
    (
        @$t_perm_tp_0,
        [AHI_EVENT_SKU].permission_id,
        [AHI_EVENT_SKU].created_by_id,
        (SELECT managed_by_id FROM [AHI_EVENT] WHERE id= [AHI_EVENT_SKU].source_id),
        (SELECT owned_by_id FROM [AHI_EVENT] WHERE id = [AHI_EVENT_SKU].source_id),
        [AHI_EVENT_SKU].team_id,
        @$t_iden_list_2,
        @$t_ip_addr_3,
        @$t_cur_user_id_4,
        @$Crtr,
        @$Mngr,
        @$Ownr
    )
)
 > 0) ORDER BY [AHI_EVENT_SKU].sort_order, [AHI_EVENT_SKU].id
 SET ROWCOUNT 0',N'@$t_perm_tp_0 nvarchar(7),@$t_perm_tp_1 nvarchar(12),@$t_iden_list_2 ntext,@$t_ip_addr_3 nvarchar(12),@$t_cur_user_id_4 char(32),@$Crtr char(32),@$Mngr char(32),@$Ownr char(32),@perms_having_can_get_id char(32),@perms_having_can_get char(32),@$t_pwarn_10 nvarchar(24),@PageSize_page_size_11 int',@$t_perm_tp_0=N'can_get',@$t_perm_tp_1=N'can_discover',@$t_iden_list_2=N'DA617F385E2E47CFA337B04A1D598F73,A73B655731924CD0B027E4F4D5FCC0A9,2618D6F5A90949BAA7E920D1B04C7EE1,473D6491E52A41D484E793C02B813C92,57DDA0412C2A4B4C96B62FB4BFB56800,5E12CD824411477AA56D9F539FA295EB,64364B8DAE994755845476077F457B44,694C8B27E5D940DAA8BD336E45EC3A63',@$t_ip_addr_3=N'10.13.106.57',@$t_cur_user_id_4='3E3DE0CE0EFC4ED5AD0E82C4B2676A97',@$Crtr='8FE5430B42014D94AE83246F299D9CC4',@$Mngr='9200A800443E4A5AAA80D0BCE5760307',@$Ownr='538B300BB2A347F396C436E9EEE1976C',@perms_having_can_get_id='93AB06D37FC84328A314324DC45DB574',@perms_having_can_get='93AB06D37FC84328A314324DC45DB574',@$t_pwarn_10=N'show_permissions_warning',@PageSize_page_size_11=1000
```

Comment: What are the exact server details of your servers, i.e. version and edition, #dedicated CPU, RAM etc.?

Comment: MS SQL SERVER 2012 enterprise(4 Processor CPU),24 GB,DB SIZE: 37 GIGS. Thanks alzaimar.

Comment: MS SQL SERVER 2012 enterprise(4 Processor CPU),24 GB RAM (OS-8GB,sql-16GB,  DB SIZE: 37 GIGS. Thanks alzaimar.

Comment: Similar issues like performance lags were rectified few days ago as the compatibility settings were of the old version. (I changed compatibility settings from 10 --> 11. (SQL 2008 = 10, SQL 2012 = 11)